Combine multiple instructions swap raydium with lookup table
I want to combine multiple instructions of swap function using addresses of lookup table(LUT). But I stuck with it when combine instructions and sign with addresses in LUT. If you guys how to fix it. Please help me. Thanks all <3
  const directionIn = poolKeys.quoteMint.toString() == toToken;
  const { minAmountOut, amountIn } = await this.calcAmountOut(
    poolKeys,
    amount,
    slippage,
    directionIn
  );

  // TODO: temp
  // https://explorer.solana.com/address/2jXTrPQoZc9j31Ggxu4CCBcGWoRisYZuzu9ntQUQAtnA/entries
  const lookupTableAddress = new PublicKey(
    "2jXTrPQoZc9j31Ggxu4CCBcGWoRisYZuzu9ntQUQAtnA"
  );
  const lookupTableAccount = (
    await this.connection.getAddressLookupTable(lookupTableAddress)
  ).value;

  const txs: TransactionInstruction[] = [];
  for (const address of lookupTableAccount.state.addresses) {
    const userTokenAccounts = await this.getOwnerTokenAccounts(address);
    const swapTransaction = await Liquidity.makeSwapInstructionSimple({
      connection: this.connection,
      makeTxVersion: useVersionedTransaction ? 0 : 1,
      poolKeys: {
        ...poolKeys,
      },
      userKeys: {
        tokenAccounts: userTokenAccounts,
        owner: address,
      },
      amountIn: amountIn,
      amountOut: minAmountOut,
      fixedSide: fixedSide,
      config: {
        bypassAssociatedCheck: false,
      },
      computeBudgetConfig: {
        microLamports: maxLamports,
      },
    });

    const instructions =
      swapTransaction.innerTransactions[0].instructions.filter(Boolean);

    txs.push(...instructions);
  }

  console.log(" ✅ - Length of txs", txs.length);

  this.recentBlock = await this.connection.getLatestBlockhash("confirmed");
  console.log(
    " ✅ - Fetched latest blockhash. Last Valid Height:",
    this.recentBlock.lastValidBlockHeight
  );

  const swapVersionedTransaction = new VersionedTransaction(
    new TransactionMessage({
      payerKey: this.wallet.publicKey,
      recentBlockhash: this.recentBlock.blockhash,
      instructions: txs,
    }).compileToV0Message([lookupTableAccount])
  );

  console.log(" ✅ - Compiled Transaction Message");

  // TODO: because LUT have 2 addresses, need signing with 2 signers
  var signerArr = [
    "PK_1", // <--------- Private key of address 1 in LUT
    "PK_1", // <--------- Private key of address 2 in LUT
  ];
  var signers: Keypair[] = [];
  signerArr.forEach((s) => {
    signers.push(Keypair.fromSecretKey(base58.decode(s)));
  });
  swapVersionedTransaction.sign([...signers]);

